# MVC form hijaxing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Controller that returns either a PartialView or a RedirectToAction result when doing an ajax request.

Now the problem is that in the View I want to either display the PartialView or Rediect to the Action depending on what the Controller returns, but I can't think of a way of differentiating the response of the Controller...

Here's my code. This works fine when a PartialView is returned by the Controller, but it displays the content of the RedirectToAction too if that was what the Controller returned:

```
$(".Form").live("submit", function () {
    $.updateForm(this, "#CodeForm");
    return false;
});

$.updateForm = function (myv, divToUpdate) {
    $.post($(myv).attr("action"),
        $(myv).serialize(),
        function (data) {
            //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            $(divToUpdate).slideUp("normal", function () {
                $(divToUpdate).html(data).slideDown("slow", "");
            });
        });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the data , check if it has a `<body>` tag, if it doesn't, it was a `PartialView`, otherwise it was a normal view.